# Ghost instances popping up in vectors

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, instantiation

This one has me stumped.  I have three classes - a large class called `Level` that contains, among other things, a multidimensional vector of pointers to `Plant` instances and a multidimensional vector of pointers to `Mob` instances; both vectors are meant to classify the mobs and plants according to their position, so that I can search for each in a smaller vector based on their approximate location, rather than cycling through all existing plants/mobs in order to find the one nearest to a given point.

The vectors are as follows, with the smallest std::vectors representing a square area of 128 pixels on each side.  Mobs and plants are classed by dividing their X and Y coords by 128 and adding them to the proper sector (I am careful that the resulting values are in fact integers).

`std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Plant*> > >* m_PlantSectors`

`std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Mob*> > >* m_AnimalSectors`

The mobs sometimes need to find plants.  Here is where the problem arises: when the mobs query the multidimensional vector, searching for plants in their approximate area (if the mob's coords/128 are, say, [1,2] it searches m_PlantSectors[2][1]), they sometimes find plants that don't exist.

Not only that, but these plants have impossible positions, on the order of 1.9777e+33 or 3.75853e-39 (for instance).  When I try to change the color of the chosen plant to red in order to find it visually, I find that none of the plants on the screen (the only plants are ones I've hand-placed) have changed color.

I've marked all the plants with an integer ID; there are 36 plants, with IDs from 1-36, but the plants my mobs find have IDs like 63 or 429 - ones that can't possibly exist, since no such number of plants was created (there is a single plant creation function that consistently reports how many plants exist, so no plants are being accidentally created).  The mobs all run off to the upper-left part of the screen after the imaginary plants, and die of starvation.

So somehow, I an creating ghost plants.  So far, I've tried two separate approaches for allowing `Mob` instances to look for `Plant` instances.  The first looks like this:

```
    float TargetDist = 256 * 256;
    Plant* Candidate = 0;
    Plant* ForageTarget = 0;
    int xSect = m_X / 128;
    int ySect = m_Y / 128;
    std::vector<Plant*> ThisSect = pLevel->CheckPSector(xSect, ySect);
    for (int i = 0; i < ThisSect.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Searching in Sector (" << ySect << ", " << xSect << ")\n";
        Candidate = ThisSect[i];
        cout << "Candidate at: " << Candidate->GetX() << ", " << Candidate->GetY() << "\n";
        Candidate->Mark();
        //Calculate distance
        float xDist = Candidate->GetX() - m_X;
        float yDist = Candidate->GetY() - m_Y;
        float tDist = sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist);
        if (tDist <= TargetDist)
        {
            ForageTarget = Candidate;
            TargetDist = tDist;
        }
    }
```

Where CheckPSector() looks like this:

```
std::vector<Plant*> Level::CheckPSector(int x, int y)
{
    return m_PlantSectors[y][x];
}
```

The second thing I tried was this:

```
        float TargetDist = 256 * 256;
        Plant* Candidate = 0;
        Plant* ForageTarget = 0;
        int xSect = m_X / 128;
        int ySect = m_Y / 128;
        std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Plant*> > >* Sectors = pLevel->AccessPlantSectors();
        for (int i = 0; i < (*Sectors)[ySect][xSect].size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "Searching in Sector (" << ySect << ", " << xSect << ")\n";
            Candidate = (*Sectors)[ySect][xSect][i];
            cout << "Candidate at: " << Candidate->GetX() << ", " << Candidate->GetY() << "\n";
            Candidate->Mark();
            //Calculate distance
            float xDist = Candidate->GetX() - m_X;
            float yDist = Candidate->GetY() - m_Y;
            float tDist = sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist);
            if (tDist <= TargetDist)
            {
                ForageTarget = Candidate;
                TargetDist = tDist;
            }
        }
```

Using this:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Plant*> > >* Level::AccessPlantSectors()
{
    return &m_PlantSectors;
}
```

Both of these, however, result in the animals finding imaginary plants and running off into the void.

I don't want to copy potentially large multidimensional vectors into `Mob` instances on a regular basis, because there will be many such instances at any one time, and I'd like the program to run somewhat smoothly.  Even so, I just tried to do the whole thing by copying the entire vector instead of just the relevant one, and I get the same result: imaginary plants.

I've never quite had a problem like this before; what could be happening here?

EDIT: Perhaps I should mention that getting the chosen plants to self-report their own position and ID fails equally, turning up absurd results, so it isn't just the functions in `Plant` I use to access private members.  Meanwhile, querying all existing plants does not reveal any with the information the ghost plants self-report.

Comment: Your question is quite long and hard to follow.  Could you consider simplifying your code and scenario, and creating a self-contained test case?  (see http://sscce.org)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right.  I'll see if I can cook up something simpler - perhaps I'll answer my own question in doing so.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are using pointers of multidimensional arrays. Smells like reading from uninitialized memory to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `m_PlantSectors` is defined as:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<Plant*> > >* m_PlantSectors
```

Then `Level::AccessPlantSectors()` should return `m_PlantSectors`, not `&m_PlantSectors` because you already have a pointer.

Likewise, `Level::CheckPSector(int x, int y)` should return `(*m_PlantSectors)[y][x]` because you need to deference the pointer before invoking the `[]` operator.

As you've written them, `Level::CheckPSector(int x, int y)` returns random memory and I'm surprised that `Level::AccessPlantSectors()` compiles.

Comment: Sorry I only saw this so late - thank you for the clarification!  I eventually managed to overcome the problem by cleaning up the code and storing the plants as pointers to locations on the heap in the first place.